# Resume build in Jenkins TIKAL Multijob plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins Multijob plugin where i put many jobs,

Job A

Job B

Job C ==> Failed

Job D

Is it possible to resume build from the failed Point for example here start it from JOB C ?

Comment: Using free or enterprise version jenkins?

Comment: i'm using the free version

Comment: Currently it not available in free version. You can read more on this using this link https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33846.

Comment: from the link u gave "This missing feature is the only reason stopping us from using the pipeline plugin. We use the Tikal Multijob plugin which allows us to resume from a phase in the pipeline. " it seems that this is available in Multijob plugin

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, the resume build functionality exist in TIKAL multijob plugin, Go to the MultiJob build and if you're the one who launched the build or the admin you'll find a Resume build button that gives you the ability to start the build at the failed point.